# Time is reset on boot

Tags: time

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (not dual-boot).  I have chrony for ntp.

Every time I boot the machine, the date is reset to the same time, about a month in the past.  This occurs regardless of whether chrony has synchronized the time via NTP, been disabled via systemctl, or whether I execute `date -s` to set the time manually.

Nothing in the journal stands out to me, but I'm not sure what I'd look for.

How can I diagnose/fix this?

**Edit:** This is running on a raspberry pi 4B

Comment: Change the internal RTC battery on your system. Ubuntu should save/restore the time from that. Lacking a Real Time Clock, run `ntpdate` before you start `chrony`. See `man ntpdate hwclock`.

Comment: Unfortunately my system doesn't have an RTC.  It's not the time isn't being counted while the system is off; when I reboot the clock is always set to the exact same time (a month ago).  Shouldn't the system remember the time it had when it shut down?

Comment: *"Shouldn't the system remember the time it had when it shut down?"* - No, it does not write that into any variable and stored in hard drive.  It almost sounds like you have a bad setting in your chrony settings like not being configured to hit a good NTP source like servers found in https://www.ntppool.org/en/zone/us

Comment: *"No, it does not write that into any variable"* This doesn't seem right.  For example, with systemd-timesyncd (the default ntp daemon), the time is stored in the timestamp of the `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock` file.  See [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-timesyncd).  I guess chrony doesn't do this ...

Comment: Apparently timesyncd doesn't do it either like you show in the arch wiki as I am using a Raspberry Pi 3b+ and nowhere does it have a time stamp written for when the time synced. Glad you found a solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was found in the [chrony docs](https://chrony-project.org/faq.html#_what_if_my_computer_does_not_have_an_rtc_or_backup_battery), focusing on devices which do not have an RTC.

On reboot, chrony attempts to compensate for the "drift" and (since my device lacks an RTC) winds up producing bogus times.  To fix this, we can pass `-s` to `chronyd`, so it sets the clock on startup to the last remembered time.

This is most easily done in `/etc/default/chrony`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-s"
```